# I can't Turn On Or Off GPS By Using Following Codes, Please Tell me What is the Reason?

Tags: java, android, gps

```
private void turnGPSOn(){
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}

private void turnGPSOff(){
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? What is (not) happening (wrong) ?

Comment: No I did not get an error message
I Print Out provider string it shows "network"

Comment: I Also tryed this one
        Intent intent2=new
        Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
        intent2.putExtra("enabled", true);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent2);
       
But this code only searches for GPS not turon it on/off

Comment: My GPS is not turning ON/OFF programmatically :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Guidelines have changed above version 4.0. You cannot change GPS off on programmatically for versions above 4.0. However, you can change wifi off-on programmatically.

Apps cannot enable or disable GPS programmatically, except perhaps on rooted devices. Please allow the user to do that.

Comment: oh ho :( thanks
i was trying for android 4.2 and 4.4 :(
Any Solution

Comment: use dialog for asking user to turn off and on the gps, and redirect to settings on ok button press.that is even better and user friendly. :)